# Vectorizing Tensor Products from Python to Matlab

Tags: python, matlab

I am in the process of converting some code from Python into Matlab. I have code working that produces the same results, but I am wondering if there may be a way to vectorize some of my for loops in the Matlab code as it take a long time to run. `X` in an Nxd matrix, `diff` is an NxNxd tensor, `kxy` is an NxN matrix, `gradK` is an NxNx2 tensor, and `sumkxy`, `dxkxy`, and `obj` are all Nxd matrices.

Here is the original Python Code:

```py
diff = x[:, None, :] - x[None, :, :]  # D_{ij, s}
kxy = np.exp(-np.sum(diff ** 2, axis=-1) / (2 * h ** 2)) / np.power(np.pi * 2.0 * h * h, d / 2) # -1 last dimension K_{ij]
gradK = -diff * kxy[:, :, None] / h ** 2  # N * N * 2
sumkxy = np.sum(kxy, axis=1)
dxkxy = np.sum(gradK, axis=1)  # N * 2    sum_{i} d_i K_{ij, s}
obj = np.sum(gradK / sumkxy[None, :, None], axis=1)  # N * 2
```

and here is my initial Matlab Code with all the for loops:

```matlab
diff = zeros([n,n,d]);
for i = 1:n
    for j = 1:n
        for k = 1:d
            diff(i,j,k) = x(i,k) - x(j,k);
        end
    end
end

kxy = exp(-sum(dif.^2, 3)/(2*h^2))/((2*pi*h^2)^(d/2));
sumkxy = sum(kxy,2);
gradK = zeros([n,n,d]);
for i = 1:n
    for j = 1:n
        for k = 1:d
            gradK(i,j,k) = -diff(i,j,k)*kxy(i, j)/h^2;
        end
    end
end

dxkxy = squeeze(sum(gradK,2));
a = zeros([n,n,d]);
for i =1:n
    for j = 1:n
        for k = 1:d
            a(i,j,k) = gradK(i,j,k)/sumkxy(i);
        end
    end
end
obj = squeeze(sum(a, 2));
```

I know a way a faster way to calculate the `kxy` term is to use the following code:

```matlab
XY = x*x';
x2= sum(x.^2, 2);
X2e = repmat(x2, 1, n);
 
H = (X2e + X2e' - 2*XY); % calculate pairwise distance
Kxy = exp(-H/(2*h^2))/((2*pi*h*h)^(d/2));
```

But then I struggle on a way to then calculate `gradK` efficiently without `diff`. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please post code that can be run as is, so we can use it. That is, define `n`, `d`, `x` etc. Also, it's good practice to avoid naming a variable `diff`,  because that's the name of a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is computation of `obj` you don't need even to compute `gradK` and `a`:

```
sx = sum(x.^2, 2);
H = sx - 2*x*x.' + sx.';

kxy = exp(-H/(2*h^2))/((2*pi*h^2)^(d/2));
kh = kxy / h^2; 
sumkxy = sum(kxy, 2);
khs = kh ./ sumkxy;
obj = khs * x - sum(khs, 2) .* x;
```

`gradK` and `dif` can be computed this way:

```
dif = reshape(x, n, 1, d) - reshape(x, 1, n, d);
gradK = -dif .* (kxy / h^2);.
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I actually end up needing the gradK term for another calculation later on but this is helpful to effectively compute the obj term easily!

Comment: @KaitlinO'Dell A vectorized computation of `gradK` is added.

Answer (score 0):

I like to try approaching problems like these by breaking it down into "subcomponents" with some bogus data that will execute quickly and that you can use to test the code functionality. The first subcomponent you might start with is your first nested loop calculating diff:

```
n = 100;
d = 50;
x = round(100*rand(n,d));

tic
diff = zeros([n,n,d]);
for i = 1:n
    for j = 1:n
        for k = 1:d
            diff(i,j,k) = x(i,k) - x(j,k);
        end
    end
end
toc
```

First, consider the innermost loop on its own:

```
...
for k = 1:d
    diff(i,j,k) = x(i,k) - x(j,k);
end
...
```

Looking at this loop (at least for me!) simplifies things greatly. To vectorize just this "subcomponent" we could write something like:

```
diff(i,j,:) = x(i,:) - x(j,:);
```

Now that the low hanging fruit is out of the way, lets consider the next layer of loop. Does doing the same trick as before work?

```
diff(i,:,:) = x(i,:) - x; % where x(:,:) can just be written as x.
```

If you aren't sure, you can check this by running both the nested loop version and the one above with the same (emphasis on same) bogus data and checking if they are equal using isequal(). To cut to the chase, it should come out the same and now your original loop is down to:

```
tic
diff = zeros([n,n,d]);
for i = 1:n
    diff(i,:,:) = x(i,:) - x;
end
toc
```

For this final bit, you can exploit matlab's matrix/array reshaping/permuting functions. Look up the documentation for reshape() or permute() for more details. In brief, if you reshape or change the order of the dimensions of one copy of x from Nxd to 1xNxd, subtracting x from another, regularly sized matrix will perform the operations elementwise in matlab. So for example:

```
diff = permute(x,[1,3,2]) - permute(x,[3,1,2]); % this is Nx1xd - 1xNxd
```

should effectively compute the tensor difference you were looking for in the first loop!

I can expand this answer to show how the other loops might be worked out if you want, but give the other ones a try first with this same logic. Hopefully, you can keep diff and then calculate kxy much faster. Without knowing how big your original matrices are, I can't say how much speedup you should expect though.

Update:

I should add, to ensure that you are doing elementwise multiplication, division and transpose operations make sure to add a '.' before each command. E.g.

```
gradK(i,j,:) = -diff(i,j,:).*kxy(i, j)/h^2;
```

For more information, look up elementwise operations in Matlab

Comment: Thank you so much for the thoughtful answer! This is very helpful. The tensor size varies for different runs but it can be up to 10000 so I think this should help a lot!

Comment: Be sure to check out rahnema1's solution when you get a better grip on the basics here! It's a relatively clean final implementation.